# Why does my min function always return None?

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to write a min method for a binary search tree, but for some reason the output is always None!
I understand that I always have to go left in order to find the minimum and that's what my code is doing but I don't understand why I always get None as an output!

```
class Tree_node():
    def __init__(self, key, val):
        self.key = key
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None



class BSearch_tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None


    def insert(self, key, val):
        if self.root==None:
            self.root=Tree_node(key,val)
        elif key == self.root.key:
            self.val=val
        elif key < self.root.key:
            left = BSearch_tree()
            left.root = self.root.left
            self.root.left=BSearch_tree.insert(left,key,val)



        elif key > self.root.key:
            right = BSearch_tree()
            right.root=self.root.right
            self.root.right=BSearch_tree.insert(right,key,val)

    def min(self):
        if self.root==None:
            return None
        current= self
        while current.root.left!=None:
            current=current.root.left
        return current
```

Comment: Your `insert()` method is not returning anything, so `self.root.left = BSearch_tree.insert(left, key, val)` ends up setting `self.root.left` to `None`.

Comment: `None` is a singleton; use `self.root is None` and `current.root.left is not None`.